# C# Передача данных из асинхронного метода

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть метод, который асинхронно выполняет загрузку файлов, как задачу методом `WebClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync`. У `WebClient` есть встроенный индикатор выполнения - `DownloadProgressChanged`. Если полю присваивать значение в методе, то `ProgressBar` работает отлично. Но если делать передачу из другого класса (по MVVM паттерну), то передача не осуществляется. Код метода:

```
class Downloader
{
    private int _progress;

    public int Progress
    {
        get { return _progress; }
        set { _progress = value; }
    }

    public async Task DownloadManyFiles(List<string> context, string pathFile)
    {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, e) => Progress = e.ProgressPercentage;

        foreach (var b in context)
        {
            string result = b.Substring(b.IndexOf("src/") + 14);
            string fileName = pathFile + @"\" + result;

            await wc.DownloadFileTaskAsync(b, fileName);
        }
        wc.Dispose();
    }
}
```

И код в ViewModel:

```
    private int _currentProgress;

    public int CurrentProgress
    {
        get { return _currentProgress; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _currentProgress, value); }
    }

    public ViewModel()
    {

        DownloadContent = new DelegateCommand<List<string>>(param =>
        {
            _downloader.DownloadManyFiles(_context.UrlsList, CurrentPath);
            CurrentProgress = _downloader.Progress;
        });
    }

    public DelegateCommand<List<string>> DownloadContent { get; }
```

И наконец, привязка ProgressBar:

```
<ProgressBar Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="{Binding CurrentProgress, Mode=OneWay}" Height="40" Width="340"/>
```

Comment: А как вы хотите, что бы `CurrentProgress` обновлялась? Написав `CurrentProgress = _downloader.Progress;` - вы не подписываете ее не на что, а лишь задаете один раз ей значение, не более. Это тоже самое, что вы напишете `CurrentProgress = 11;`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я так понял, нужно организовать связку событий между двумя классами. Только как это сделать?

Comment: Ну у вас несколько вариантов по сути: 1. Это сделать у `Progress` поддержку INPC и привязываться напрямую к нему. 2. `WebClient` вынести за метод, сделать его публичным и в VM подписаться на событие `DownloadProgressChanged`. 3. Сделать свое событие, с помощью которого вы будете оповещать об изменение `Progress`. 4. Еще как вариант (не очень хороший), в `CurrentProgress` использовать не `_currentProgress`, а `_downloader._progress` (сделав его публичным), но тут уж лучше INPC сделать и привязать напрямую. Лично я обычно делаю свой event, который оповещает нужные VM об изменение значения.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ нашел выход создав свое событие, которое принимает на вход результат работы события DownloadProgressChanged. Спасибо за помощь.